# c++ multiple connection handling

Tags: c++

I need to track multiple connections connected to one socket. I found that good ways are to use thread, fork, select or pool. I am thinking of creating a new object of class for example client for each connection so that I can work with each connection in different way but use an output of one connection in other conns. Is it a good way or I should find a way throught fork, thread etc.?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you want to send output from one connection to other connections, it'll be easier to coordinate from one process, so any of those options *except* `fork`....  The problems with `fork` are that after forking a child to handle one connection, the child process won't have any access to later sockets accepted by the parent, and that even for socket descriptors that are accessible from both processes it'll be harder to work out when it's safe to write without intermingling output.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Am I right that I can track new conns with integer newsockfd I got from newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);.

Comment: You're welcome.  Yes - your `newsockfd` there is all you need to send and receive data over the new peer-to-peer connection.